# Convert class component to functional components using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to convert this class component to functional component using hooks

```
import React, { Component, cloneElement } from 'react';

class Dialog extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.id = uuid();       
   }
   render(){
     return ( <div>Hello Dialog</div> );
  }
}
```

This component is initiated with a specific ID because I may have to use multiple instances of them. How can I achieve this if I use functional component?

Comment: You can make use of `React.useRef`. If ur ref `current` is empty, try to set it to a `uuid()`, else it means u already have one and you can skip it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may store it in state:

```
const [id] = useState(uuid()); // uuid will be called in every render but only the first one will be used for initiation 

// or using lazy initial state
const [id] = useState(() => uuid()); // uuid will only be called once for initiation
```

You may also store it in React ref:

```
const id = useRef(null);
if(!id.current) {
    // initialise 
    id.current = uuid();
}
// To access it’s value
console.log(id.current);
```

Answer (score 4):

One solution would be to use `useEffect` to create your ID at the first render, and store it in the state :

```
const Dialog = () => {
    const [id, setId] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setId(uuid())
    }, [])

    return <div>Hello Dialog</div>
}
```

Giving an empty array as the second parameter of `useEffect` makes it unable to trigger more than once.

But another extremely simple solution could be to just... create it outside of your component :

```
const id = uuid();

const Dialog = () => {
    return <div>Hello Dialog</div>
}
```

Comment: Or it can also be `const [id, setId] = useState(uuid())`.

Comment: @norbitrial Well, I thought about it, but that would mean that the `useState` hook is going to be called with a different value at each rendering since `uuid` will be executed everytime. I normally shouldn't have any side effects, but since I am not sure about it , I didn't include it

Comment: I guess if you pass a value to `useState` then it will be kept until the life of the component so technically it won't be changed on render. It will be changed once `setId` is called.

Comment: Avoid that extremely simple solution unless you are sure there  will be no more than a single ‘Dialog’ component mounted at the same time or the randomness of the Id doesn’t matter(in this case, you don’t have to use uuid).

Comment: Also note that with this useEffect method, id will be null in the first render since useEffect runs after render.

Answer (score 1):

Any instance property becomes a ref pretty much, and you would access `idRef.current` in this case for the id

```js
function Dialog() {
  const idRef = useRef(uuid())
  return <div>Hello Dialog</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all, your solutions works well. I also try this solution and I find it OK too: replace `this.id` with `Dialog.id`. Is there any downside with this solution?