# React native : How can I turn the class component code into a function component with hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

How can I turn the following code into a function component with hooks?
In my example I use a class component
And I want to change the code to a function component form

```
export default class Modal2 extends Component {
  state = {
    placeName: "",
    errorMsg: null
  };

placeNameChangedHandler = val => {
    this.setState({
      placeName: val,
      errorMsg: null
    });
  };

onConfirm = () => {
    const { placeName } = this.state;
    const { onConfirm, onHideModal } = this.props;
    if (placeName.trim().length > 5) {
      onConfirm("Cancel", placeName);
      onHideModal();
      this.setState({ placeName: "", errorMsg: null })
    } else {
      this.setState({ errorMsg: "must 5 letters" });
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert class component to functional components using hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62863369/convert-class-component-to-functional-components-using-hooks)

Answer (score 3):

That's how it should look after converting it.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Modal2(props) {
 const [desiredStateName, setDesiredStateName] = useState({
    placeName: "",
    errorMsg: null
  });


placeNameChangedHandler = val => {
  setDesiredStateName({
      placeName: val,
      errorMsg: null
    });
  };

onConfirm = () => {
    const { placeName } = desiredStateName.placeName;
    const { onConfirm, onHideModal } = props;
    if (placeName.trim().length > 5) {
      onConfirm("Cancel", placeName);
      onHideModal();
      setDesiredStateName({ placeName: "", errorMsg: null })
    } else {
     setDesiredStateName((prevState)=>{
        return{ ...prevState,errorMsg: "must 5 letters" }
    })
  }
  };
}
export default Modal2;
```

Also, a quick guide of how you are able to do it by [yourself](https://olinations.medium.com/10-steps-to-convert-a-react-class-component-to-a-functional-component-with-hooks-ab198e0fa139)

Comment: it gives error on :
setDesiredStateName((prevState)=>{ ...prevState,errorMsg: "must 5 letters" });

Answer (score 1):

Have a try by replacing your code with the below code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default Modal2 = props => {

    const [placeName, setPlaceName] = useState("")
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null)

    placeNameChangedHandler = val => {
        setPlaceName(val)
        setErrorMsg(null)
    };

    onConfirm = () => {
        const { onConfirm, onHideModal } = props;
        if (placeName.trim().length > 5) {
            onConfirm("Cancel", placeName);
            onHideModal();
            setPlaceName("")
            setErrorMsg(null)
        } else {
            setErrorMsg("must 5 letters")
        }
    };
}
```